# jQuery UI autocomplete returning [object Object]

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to create a site search similar to Google using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plug-in. The problem is my website searches for the string "[object Object]" instead of the value that I clicked. Every selection returns: "Your search for "[object Object]" did not match any products."

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "SEO",
        "Responsive Web Design",
        "Google Local",
        "Twitter",
        "Social Media",
        "Web Design",
        "What is Google Authorship",
        "NFL",
        "Contact Advanced IFX",
        "Search Engine Optimization",
        "Kevin Sullivan",
        "Fantasy Football RB Rankings 2013",
        "Fantasy Football",
        "How to Buy Twitter Followers",
        "Advanced IFX",
        "Social Media Marketing",
        "Advanced Marketing Trends",
        "NFL Schedule 2013-2014 Season",
        "Fantasy Football Breakdown",
    ];
    $(".search_box").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var searchTerm = ui.item;
            $('.search_box').val(searchTerm);
            $('form.search').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JY6Sf/. You shouldn't need the line ` $('.search_box').val(searchTerm);` though.

Comment: After I took the $('.search_box').val(searchTerm); out, the autocomplete drop down only executes the letter in the search box. EX: I start to search for web design, after just the w I can see web design in the aurocomplete drop down, but when I click on it, it just searches for "w".

Comment: Doesn't happen in the fiddle. You must have other code that's conflicting.

Comment: Well that narrows it down. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the line

```
$('.search_box').val(searchTerm);
```

But change the previous line to

```
var searchTerm = ui.item.label;
```

That will do it.

Look in the log of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ntb7G/

Comment: I can't begin to thank you enough Alex. That has been driving me nuts for weeks. You Rock! If I can return the favor in anyway please let me know. This site is amazing!!

Comment: You're welcome. Just glad we could see it through until the end!